# Calculate variance of product of random variables

Tags: probability

[image]

**Correct Answer: 44.64**

My work:
Using fact that they are independent,
$Var(XZ) = E[X^2Z^2]-E[XZ]^2 = E[X^2]E[Z^2]-E[X]^2E[Z]^2$, so I just have to find first and second raw moment and plug in.

X ~exp($\lambda = 1/8)$, so $E[X] = 1/8, E[X]^2 = Var(X) + E[X]^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} + (\frac{1}{\lambda})^2 = 8^2 + 8^2 = 128$.

For Z, I am not sure. I did $E[Z] = (1)(0.45) + (0.55)(\int_{0}^{1}zdz)$, and likewise for second moment. I get 47 as answer, which is off from correct answer of 44. Is that correct integrals for Z?

Comment: The question is nor properly stated,The distrbution of $Z$ is not specified completely and it is not possible to find the mean and variance of $Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the claimed answer of $44.64$, I surmise that the intended distribution for $Z$ is $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p = 0.45)$ with mass function $$\Pr[Z = z] = \begin{cases} 0.45, & z = 1 \\ 0.55, & \color{red}{z = 0}. \end{cases}$$  The calculation proceeds as follows via the law of total variance:
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}[ZX] &= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[ZX \mid Z]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[ZX \mid Z]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[Z^2 \operatorname{Var}[X]] + \operatorname{Var}[Z \operatorname{E}[X]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[Z^2]\operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{E}[X]^2 \operatorname{Var}[Z].
\end{align*}$$
Since $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\mu = 8)$, we have $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \mu = 8, \quad \operatorname{Var}[X] = \mu^2 = 64;$$ and we also have $$\operatorname{E}[Z^2] = \operatorname{E}[Z] = p = 0.45, \quad \operatorname{Var}[Z] = p(1-p) = 0.2475.$$  Therefore, $$\operatorname{Var}[ZX] = (0.45)(64) + (8^2)(0.2475) = 44.64.$$  But had the answer not been supplied, it would not have been possible to guess what the question originally intended.